# I cannot create a database file with SQL Server Express and Entity Framework

Tags: entity-framework, sql-server-express

I have the following code:

```
public DataInitializer() {
            Database.SetInitializer<DataContext>(null);
            try {
                using (var context = new DataContext()) {
                    if (!context.Database.Exists())
                    {
                        ((IObjectContextAdapter)context).ObjectContext.CreateDatabase();
                    }
                }

            }
            catch (Exception ex) {
                throw new InvalidOperationException("The Data database could not be initialized", ex);
            }
        }
```

and

```
 public class DataContext : DbContext
    {
        public DataContext() : base("xxdata") { }
        protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
            modelBuilder.Conventions.Remove<PluralizingTableNameConvention>();
        }
        public DbSet<Application> Applications { get; set; }
    }
```

The code gets executed when I step through it but it seems like no database file is created (SQL Server Express).

Is there something obvious that I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create an inherited class as below;

```
public class DataContextInitializer : DropCreateDatabaseAlways<DataContext>
    {
        protected override void Seed(DataContext context)
        {
          //Seed data if you want
        }
    }
```

and add this to your `Global.asax`

```
protected void Application_Start()
{
    //Add your database initializer code 
    Database.SetInitializer(new DataContextInitializer());
}
```

Comment: Just tried and it is saying "Has some invalid arguments". I will look into this a bit more.

Comment: @Gemma See my update.Previously , you had not inherited the class from some class like `DropCreateDatabaseAlways<T>` now put this class as you want. and check if it works.Also, you don't need to add any other details in this class as you have put `CreateDatabase`. EF will automatically create it for you.

Comment: I tried this but it seems to do nothing. Will it only work if I have something inside the Seed method?  Maybe I need a constructor in DataContextInitializer ?

Comment: @Gemma No, its all right if you don't do seeding. tell me when are you loooking for a database? It will not be created until you try to add something in it. Try to add `Application` to the database through code. The database is created only when you make an instance of your context class or try to add something in database. try this, I think this is your problem.